# Increase QPen Width

Tags: python, pyqt, qpainter, qpen

I need to increase the pen width for the below code using Painter/QPen, but nothing that I try works.  Can someone please point me in the right direction?

```
    while c_len < MAX_LENGTH:
        # Set the pen color for this segment
        sat = 200 * (MAX_LENGTH - c_len) / MAX_LENGTH
        hue = (color + 130 * (height - y_s) / height) % 360
        p.setPen(QPen(QColor_HSV(hue, sat, 255, 20), 2))
```

Comment: You're not increasing *anything*. Not only the `c_len` is not used for the pen, but you are not even *actually* increasing its value.

Comment: I realize that.  All of my attempts at increasing the width have failed... so I didn't even out that part in.

Comment: If we can't see those attempts, how can we help you? We cannot tell you what is wrong with your code if you don't show us what you did.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [setWidth](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtGui/QPen.html#PySide2.QtGui.PySide2.QtGui.QPen.setWidth) method of QPen like so:

```
while c_len < MAX_LENGTH:
    # Set the pen color for this segment
    sat = 200 * (MAX_LENGTH - c_len) / MAX_LENGTH
    hue = (color + 130 * (height - y_s) / height) % 360
    pen = QPen(QColor_HSV(hue, sat, 255, 20))
    pen.setWidth(2)
    p.setPen(pen)
```

Just giving the value 2 to the constructor does not work, because there is no matching signature for your arguments.

As an alternative, use arguments that are supported by the signature:

```
pen = QPen(QColor_HSV(hue, sat, 255, 20), 2, QtCore.Qt.SolidLine)
```

This is preferred, as it avoids a separate function call which is [slow](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips) in Python.